# Apt-mirror: Illegal division by zero

Tags: apt-mirror

I'm trying to set up an `apt-mirror` service for an offline repository but I've hit a weird error.  I edited my `mirror.list` file to contain the proper paths (a USB drive mounted at `/media/Ubuntu`) but when I try to run `apt-mirror`, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-mirror /etc/apt/mirror.list
Argument "M-BM- " isn't numeric in numeric lt (<) at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 204.
Downloading 982 index files using   threads...
Illegal division by zero at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 209.
```

Any ideas as to what this could mean?

Comment: Though [this has been answered beautifully](http://askubuntu.com/a/243598/22949), it is still a bug for `apt-mirror` to crash with a division by zero error when a configuration file is malformed. I highly recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs); [Gilles' analysis](http://askubuntu.com/a/243598/22949) should help and the information from it can be included in the bug report to assist triagers and developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm looking at my crystal ball… It's a bit hazy… Ah, there it is.

You have an unbreakable space after `nthreads` in your `mirror.list` file. Replace it by a normal space.

<sub>Explanation: line 204 in the script is where `apt-mirror` compares the number of URLS — which is always numeric — with the value of the `nthreads` configuration setting. The parser for configuration settings doesn't check for numeric values, so a non-numeric value isn't detected until the setting is used. `M-BM-` displays two unprintable bytes c2a0 (0x42=`B` and 0x20=space, with `M-` indicating +0x80); this two-byte sequence encodes the unbreakable space in UTF-8.</sub>

In the future, **post the full content of your configuration file** when you ask such questions.

Comment: This deserves many upvotes. It's a very neat explanation, shows what's going on and is therefore very interesting out of a simple cause for an issue!